# Is anything getting written to the boot partition?

Tags: boot, readwrite

I want to maximize the lifespan of my SD card as long as possible, the Pi is looking at a everyday 10h use for several years to come.
Now I would like to have the boot partition to be writable to be able to alter some config files my application uses but I've seen a few guides regarding a read-only systems, also making the boot partition read-only.
Does that have any reason other than security or is the system writing anything on this partition except for firmware updates.

Comment: Maybe you could save your self some time and use a ram disk system like TinyCoreLinux with on demand persistence already included? http://tinycorelinux.net/ports.html

Comment: Sounds interesting but Raspbian is an absolute must for this project.

Comment: Then use "IPE – Industrial Perennial Environment R1". That is a Raspbian tailored to survive unexpected power downs. You can find it here: http://nutcom.hu/ipe-r1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system will not write to the boot partition unless you ask it to by editing a boot configuration file (config.txt, cmdline.txt) or by updating the firmware.